# How do i display images in reverse with RepeaterImages in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

This code displays the images in alphabetical order, since i appended the date to it, it will always add the newest image to the end. How can I reverse it? I want the newest image to be shown first.

This is the code where I upload and save the images:

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HHmmtt") + FileUpload1.FileName);
```

This is where I display the images:

```
string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images"));
        List<String> images = new List<string>(filesindirectory.Count());

        foreach (string item in filesindirectory)
        {
            if (System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item) != "Thumbs.db")
            {
                images.Add(String.Format("/Images/{0}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item)));
            }
        }

        RepeaterImages.DataSource = images;
        RepeaterImages.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really just want reverse order then use [`Reverse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images"))
                               .Reverse()
                               .ToArray();
```

if you want to sort them in descending order by `LastWriteTime` then use this:

```
string[] filesindirectory = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Images"))
                               .EnumerateFiles()
                               .OrderByDescending(n => n.LastWriteTime)
                               .Select(n => n.FullName)
                               .ToArray();
```